# hoverIntent not working on first hover

Tags: jquery, hoverintent

So I'm trying to refactor some jQuery mouseenters using hoverIntent. Everthing works when I call hoverIntent individually for each nav item but when I try to use the following code, **nothing happens on the first mouseover**, then it works:

```
$('.navItem1').on('hover', function(){
    navHoverIntent(this);
});

$('.navItem2').on('hover', function(){
    navHoverIntent(this);
});

$('.navItem3').on('hover', function(){
    navHoverIntent(this);
});

$('.navItem4').on('hover', function(){
    navHoverIntent(this);

});

function navHoverIntent(className) {
//set some vars for use in hoverIntent
var currentDiv = $(className); 
var cubeImg = currentDiv.find('img');
var childDivs = currentDiv.find('div'); 
var navTitle = childDivs[0]; 
var subNav = childDivs[1]; 
//now calling hoverIntent

currentDiv.hoverIntent({
    over: function(){
        if(cubeImg.css("display")=="block"){
        navTitle.css("color","#262261");
        }
        currentDiv.css("backgroundColor","#d7d7d7");
        $(subNav).show();
        },
    out: function(){
        if(cubeImg.css("display")=="block"){
        navTitle.css("color","#8CC640");
        currentDiv.css("backgroundColor","#262261");
        }else{
        currentDiv.css("backgroundColor","transparent");
        $("#subnav1").hide();
        $("#subnav2").hide();
        $("#subnav3").hide();
        $("#subnav4").hide();
        }
        },

    });
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In case you still need an answer for this, from what i can see your problem is that on the first hover you are adding the event listener (but it is not triggered too).

Also you are adding a new event listener on each hover, without removing the old one.

If this is not the intended behavior, you could call that function for each "*navItem*" by yourself and remove it from hover.

Hope it help